# Finding a converging series, which when multiplied by another, diverges

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I was thinking of using some sort of an alternating sequence  for $(a_{n})_{n=1}$, but wasn't sure where to go. I know that an alternating series is not divergent, it's just not convergent since it doesn't tend to infinity but rather oscillates between two numbers.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Link to previously asked question: [Sequences and series and the alternating series test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3154519/sequences-and-series-and-the-alternating-series-test)

If the solutions are correct, can someone explain them properly please.

Comment: Why not let $a_n$ be the terms of a convergent nonalternating series and render $q_n=1/a_n$?  Am I missing something subtle in the language here?

Comment: @OscarLanzi $q_n$ is given to you, you're not free to define it.

Comment: You could define $a_n = 1_n/q_n$ where $1_n$ is either 0 or 1; $1_n=1$ only when $q_n>0$ and $q_n$ is "sufficiently large;" $1_n=1$ for an infinite number of indices $n$. It remains to define a precise condition for "sufficiently large."

Answer (score 2):

We can find integers $n_1<n_2<\cdots$ such that $q_{n_k} >2^{k}$. Let $a_n=0$ if $n \notin \{n_1,n_2,\cdots\}$ and $a_{n_k}=q_{n_k}^{-1}$. $\sum a_n =\sum a_{n_k} <\sum \frac 1 {2^{k}} <\infty$ and $\sum a_nq_n$ does not converge because the general term of the series does not tend to $0$.